# what does it mean: $L^1_{loc}(U)$

Tags: integration, general-topology, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I cannot find the definition of this symbol $L^1_{loc}(U)$ in this [book](http://62.182.86.140/main/857000/96727826294444c8132e5ca6d90bc36e/%28Graduate%20Studies%20in%20Mathematics%29%20Lawrence%20C.%20Evans%20-%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations_%20Second%20Edition%20-AMS%20%282010%29.djvu) (If the link doesn't start to download, copy it nad paste into your browser.) in the definition above (3).

[image]

Comment: $u$ is locally integrable in $U$ if for any compact subset $K$ of $U$, $\int_K|u|<\infty$.

Comment: Functions which are intergable on every compact subset of $U$.

Comment: For next time, all of the notation in Evans is defined in the first section of the appendix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the function is locally $L^1$, i.e. it is in $L^1(K)$ for every compact subset $K$ of $U$.